# How best to share a global computed in main with a dynamically loaded library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld-preload

In my program I compute a global variable and spawn a subprogram loading a shared library (this is SSCCE so it's silly, but smallest possible, example).

`main.c` 
compiled with
`gcc main.c common.o -o program`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;

extern int g_common;

int main() {
    char *argv[2] = {"/bin/true", NULL};

    // SSCCE HACK: don't do this at home!
    // environ[0] is unimportant so we replace it
    environ[0] = "LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/foobar.so";

    g_common = 1;
    printf("main: g_common is %d\n", g_common);

    if (!fork())
        execve(*argv, argv, environ);
}
```

The global variable is defined in

`common.c` compiled with `gcc -fPIC -rdynamic -c common.c`:

```
int g_common;
```

and the dyno library is

`foobar.c` compiled with

`gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-init,init common.o foobar.c -o /tmp/foobar.so`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int g_common;

void init() {
    printf("foobar.so: g_common is %d\n", g_common);
}
```

Now you can guess what I am trying to do here.

In the main `program` I want to compute something, here `g_common` . In reality this is a long computation so I only want to do it once.

Then later in the program, I spawn subprograms, that dynamically preload a library, and in that library I want to use the previously calculated value.

Here it is just one program but in reality there are thousands and I don't want to recompute the `g_common` value each time in the `init()` function for the preloaded library.

Of course what I am trying to do does not work, the program prints 1 but the subprograms prints 0 (uninitialized).  That is because there are two instances of `g_common`.

OK, so how to do this correctly, so I only calculate `g_common` once?

Comment: You can't do that in that way, execve erase almost all of your previous program. Use IPC like pipe.

Comment: While you use `execve()`, there's nothing you can do.  The replacement of the current process with the new process means that `g_common` is reset to 0.  If you're going to share values across process invocations, you're going to need to look at shared memory, or saving the value in a file and reading it from the file in the replacement process, or some other IPC mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I used the suggestion by Jonathan Leffler to use shared memory.  I want to post this as benefit to future newbies.

To Jonathan Leffler should go all the credit, not to me.

In `main()`:

```
int fd;
fd = shm_open("g_common", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 
        S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
write(fd, "foo", 4);
```

In `foobar.c` `init()`:

```
int fd = shm_open("g_common", O_RDONLY, 0);
void *bytes = mmap(NULL, 4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
printf("g_common is %s\n", (char *)bytes);
```

And of course `common.c` is not needed.